# Joda Time on Android not computing correctly

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

So, I am trying to computer the difference between two dates in time, and out puting that difference in days, hours, and minutes. I've been running this sample code just as a java console application and it works fine, however, when I try to do the same thing in Android, I get garbage data. Is Joda Time too complex for Android? Should I try out Date4j as an alternative?

```
import java.util.; import org.joda.;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class time {

        //(5000);
        final static long MILLIS_IN_DAY = 86400000;
        final static long MILLIS_IN_HOUR = 3600000;
        final static long MILLIS_IN_MINUTE = 60000;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        long day, hour, minute;

        //MAKE SURE TO CHECK IF USER SET(LATER)
        // DateTime(2013,9,12,0,0)
                DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2013,9,17,0,0);
                DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2013,9,12,21,30);


                //long date = d2.getMillis();

                DateTime d3 = new DateTime();

                long diffInMillis = d3.getMillis() - d1.getMillis();
                minute = (diffInMillis/MILLIS_IN_MINUTE)%60;
                hour = (diffInMillis/MILLIS_IN_HOUR)%24;
                day = (diffInMillis/MILLIS_IN_DAY);


                System.out.println(Long.toString(d1.getMillis()));
                System.out.println(Long.toString(d2.getMillis()));  

                System.out.println(Long.toString(d3.getMillis()));

                System.out.println(Long.toString(diffInMillis));

                System.out.println("Minutes:");
                System.out.println(Long.toString(minute));
                System.out.println("Hours:");
                System.out.println(Long.toString(hour));
                System.out.println("Days:");
                System.out.println(Long.toString(day));
    }
    }
```

Comment: `Is Joda Time too complex for Android?` What does that even mean?

Comment: define "garbage data", that's a bit too unspecific. (i.e. post expected and actual result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't calculate this values manually. Calculate with Joda-Time methods. There is no reason to use `Joda` and don't use `Joda`'s methods
E.g.
with [Days](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html), [Hours](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Hours.html), [Mintes](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html)

```
    System.out.println("Minutes:");
    System.out.println(Minutes.minutesBetween(d2, d1).getMinutes() % 60);
    System.out.println("Hours:");
    System.out.println(Hours.hoursBetween(d2, d1).getHours() % 24);
    System.out.println("Days:");
    System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(d2, d1).getDays());
```

or with [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)

```
    Period period = new Period(d2, d1);
    System.out.println("Minutes:");
    System.out.println(period.getMinutes());
    System.out.println("Hours:");
    System.out.println(period.getHours());
    System.out.println("Days:");
    System.out.println(period.getDays());
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Period class, Thank you for that. I used it and things computed much better. However, for any future readers, I did find one problem with the getDays() methood, it wil return either 0,1,2,3,4,5,6- but never anything more. Since I was trying to get a sum of total days, this is what I ended up doing:                          `Period p1 = new Period(quitDate1,d1.getMillis());
long s = d1.getMillis() - quitDate1;
float x = (float)s/MILLIS_IN_DAY;
day = (int)x; 
minute = p1.getMinutes();
hour = p1.getHours();`